# How to plot a violin scatter boxplot (in R)?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I just came by the following plot:

[image]

And wondered how can it be done in R?  (or other softwares)

**Update 10.03.11**: Thank you everyone who participated in answering this question - you gave wonderful solutions!  I've compiled all the solution presented here (as well as some others I've came by online) in [a post on my blog](http://www.r-statistics.com/2011/03/beeswarm-boxplot-and-plotting-it-with-r/).

Comment: This is maybe a stupid comment, but what does the position of dots suppose to mean?

Comment: You mean in the X or Y axis ?

Comment: It wasn't a stupid comment because the answer to how to plot that is plot(x,y).  I'm sure mbq was trying to get at the idea that what you're trying to do may be something other than a simple scatter plot.

Comment: It's also something other than a simple violin plot since that's supposed to be symmetric around the vertical axis.

Comment: @Tal, @John -- I know how standard vioplot works, but I can't figure out how those points were obtained (and as I see not only me, while it is crucial for producing good answer) -- some kind of stem? Or maybe someone just thought that filling vioplot with distorted polka dots is a good idea?

Comment: Hello John and mbq.  John, I didn't say (nor think) that the comment was stupid.  Now regarding the plot, I came across it in a recent article.  The article stated they used SAS to create it. More then this I can not offer at this time.

Comment: I'm guessing that the dots are simply jittered observations with jitter distance determined by the width of the vioplot.

Comment: Hello Rob - I suspect that the dots are attempting to simply get distributed evenly by the width of the violin. Otherwise, I wouldn't understand how no dots in the image overlap each other (except for the ones at the bottom, where there is no room for all the dots)

Comment: I've seen that type of graph before, can't remember which software was used, but the x position was just "random" jitter (proportional to the density at that point anyways). Personally, I find those a bit though to read, I'm more of a box-and-whiskers plot I guess :)

Comment: @Tal: Please go find the original reference to this chart.  Where did you get the picture from?  At this point, we have no idea what it's supposed to be or mean.  It isn't a violin or box chart (at least not in any traditional sense).

Comment: OK, I found what the software was. It's a "column scatter plot" made in GraphPad Prism. See for instance http://graphpad.com/help/prism5/prism5help.html?what_is_a_frequency_distribution.htm . I found some reference to those also here: http://www.originlab.com/www/products/GraphGallery.aspx?GID=104&s=8&lm=215

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make.Funny.Plot does more or less what I think it should do. To be adapted according to your own needs, and might be optimized a bit, but this should be a nice start.

```
Make.Funny.Plot <- function(x){
    unique.vals <- length(unique(x))
    N <- length(x)
    N.val <- min(N/20,unique.vals)

    if(unique.vals>N.val){
      x <- ave(x,cut(x,N.val),FUN=min)
      x <- signif(x,4)
    }
    # construct the outline of the plot
    outline <- as.vector(table(x))
    outline <- outline/max(outline)

    # determine some correction to make the V shape,
    # based on the range
    y.corr <- diff(range(x))*0.05

    # Get the unique values
    yval <- sort(unique(x))

    plot(c(-1,1),c(min(yval),max(yval)),
        type="n",xaxt="n",xlab="")

    for(i in 1:length(yval)){
        n <- sum(x==yval[i])
        x.plot <- seq(-outline[i],outline[i],length=n)
        y.plot <- yval[i]+abs(x.plot)*y.corr
        points(x.plot,y.plot,pch=19,cex=0.5)
    }
}

N <- 500
x <- rpois(N,4)+abs(rnorm(N))
Make.Funny.Plot(x)
```

EDIT : corrected so it always works.

Comment: Found one problem with it: If cut returns an empty level, you get an error.

Comment: +1 Good job! Still I think something is missing -- that original plot is asymmetric.

Comment: @mbq? Something missing? I just optimized that original plot. It's not a bug, it's a feature! ;-)

Comment: @Joris Maybe try using `cut2` from Hmisc instead of `cut`?

Comment: @chl If I don't have to load other libraries, I rather avoid it. I just used the wrong number in the for-loop, that has been corrected now.

Comment: @Joris so you know the original plot's definition?

Comment: This will add a little bit of randomness:
`x.plot <- sample(seq(-outline[i],outline[i],outline[i]/25), n, replace=T)`

Comment: @mbq. No, I just have too much time on my hands, the academic year has yet to start.

Answer (score 8):

I recently came upon [the beeswarm package](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/~eklund/beeswarm/), that bears some similarity.

> The bee swarm plot is a
>   one-dimensional scatter plot like
>   "stripchart", but with closely-packed,
>   non-overlapping points.

Here's an example:

```
  library(beeswarm)
  beeswarm(time_survival ~ event_survival, data = breast,
    method = 'smile',
    pch = 16, pwcol = as.numeric(ER),
    xlab = '', ylab = 'Follow-up time (months)',
    labels = c('Censored', 'Metastasis'))
  legend('topright', legend = levels(breast$ER),
    title = 'ER', pch = 16, col = 1:2)
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [eklund at www.cbs.dtu.dk](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/~eklund/beeswarm/beeswarm_example_03.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I have come up with the code similar to Joris, still I think this is more than a stem plot; here I mean that they y value in each series is a absolute value of a distance to the in-bin mean, and x value is more about whether the value is lower or higher than mean.
Example code (sometimes throws warnings but works):

```
px<-function(x,N=40,...){
x<-sort(x);

#Cutting in bins
cut(x,N)->p;

#Calculate the means over bins
sapply(levels(p),function(i) mean(x[p==i]))->meansl;
means<-meansl[p];

#Calculate the mins over bins
sapply(levels(p),function(i) min(x[p==i]))->minl;
mins<-minl[p];

#Each dot is one value.
#X is an order of a value inside bin, moved so that the values lower than bin mean go below 0
X<-rep(0,length(x));
for(e in levels(p)) X[p==e]<-(1:sum(p==e))-1-sum((x-means)[p==e]<0);
#Y is a bin minum + absolute value of a difference between value and its bin mean
plot(X,mins+abs(x-means),pch=19,cex=0.5,...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you mbq, I was wondering who's answer to pick.  I choose Joris, simply since he wrapped it up.  Either way - both answers are great and won my +1 vote.  Cheers - Tal

Answer (score 2):

Try the [vioplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vioplot/index.html) package:

```
library(vioplot)
vioplot(rnorm(100))
```

(with awful default color ;-)

There is also wvioplot() in the [wvioplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wvioplot/index.html) package, for weighted violin plot, and [beanplot](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/c01/paper), which combines violin and rug plots. They are also available through the [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html) package, see `?panel.violin`.

Comment: That doesn't produce a scatterplot, does it?

Comment: @Shane no, it's just a variation of the boxplot with an added kernel density estimate

Comment: @Shane @Tal BTW, Box-percentile plot are better (`bpplot` in the `Hmisc` package).

Comment: Hi chl.  Thank you for the answer.  I remember coming by that function, but as Shane said - it doesn't produce the scatter plot element.  I'll +1 for the good intentions - but will keep this question open :).  Cheers, Tal

Comment: @Tal Well, I'll try to figure out myself how to make it in R; I think it would not be so difficult using `stripchart()` or a jittering procedure.

Comment: Hi chl, thanks for giving this a shot.  The code used here:   http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sjm217/projects/graphics/  Might be a good start (since it succeeds in superimposing dots, instead of just jittering them)

Answer (score 2):

Since this hasn't been mentioned yet, there is also [ggbeeswarm](https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm) as a relatively new R package based on ggplot2.

Which adds another geom to ggplot to be used instead of geom_jitter or the like.

In particular **geom_quasirandom** (see second example below) produces really good results and I have in fact adapted it as default plot.

Noteworthy is also the package [vipor](https://github.com/sherrillmix/vipor) (VIolin POints in R) which produces plots using the standard R graphics and is in fact also used by ggbeeswarm behind the scenes.

```r
set.seed(12345)
install.packages('ggbeeswarm')
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbeeswarm)

ggplot(iris,aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_beeswarm()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris,aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_quasirandom()
```

[image]

```r
#compare to jitter
ggplot(iris,aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_jitter()
```

[image]